# Django one-to-many (association same table)

Tags: django, associations

I am new to Djnago's ORM.

I have a resource `Thing` that has tags `Tag`

Normally I would have three tables:

1. `things`
2. `tags`
3. `thing_tag_associations`

When I read one-to-many posts on Django, they usually have to do with an object that's has many fields foreign-keyed to many tables.

How should I set up a Django model that uses one resource that has zero-to-many associations to the same table?

**Are zero-to-many association tables using models supported in Django?**

Comment: I am not sure whether I got your question, but maybe you are talking about many-to-many relationship? `things`, `tags`, `thing_to_tag` that may have 0 entries or many?

Comment: Shoot. You might be right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are talking about many-to-many relationship? `things`, `tags`, `thing_to_tag`that may have 0 entries or many.

Consider using `tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)` in your `Thing` model.

Thus, a `Thing` would have `tags` field and a tag would have `things` (through table `thing_tags` would be created and managed automatically)

For more information, look at these docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/